# limit displace mesh to one uv face

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I have a dem (baked texture)
which I'm using to displace a uv face (projected from view, bounds and aspect)

the issue being both the front face AND the back face are displaced, how do I only target one face in geometry nodes?

In the provided picture, the desired uv is in black material and everything else in white material ...

[image: desired displacement black, unwanted displacement white]

I'm on blender 3.5 using cycles and supported feature set,
on apple m1, ventura 13.4

... just had a little time to think and perhaps the question should be rephrased ...
I'm using "project from view" for uv mapping for accuracy, this unfortunately maps ALL faces, hence ALL faces are displaced ... so the question then becomes **how do I uv map via "project from view" only the selected area/face?**

Comment: When using the "project from view" uv unwrapping operator, simply have only the top vertices selected. Or in the situation you're know, select the bottom vertices and uv unwrap them differently (or just when you select the vertices, scale the uv loops down to 0 in the uv editor and move to a corner).

Comment: appreciate the response @MarkusvonBroady. I've tried both all of your suggestions already, none of which work or are applicable. I have to "project from view" for accuracy. As per the screen shot, from what I've read and my experience as far, selecting a single face doesn't work ... all faces are selected and "stacked" looking like a single face in the editor but when you displace you can see the sides as well as teh back displace too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could limit the *Set Position* offset by *Position*, such as here:

[image]

Comment: ooooh, this has promise :) ... an initial experiment shows promise tho also generates a lot of articles. I'll play with it a bit and see if I can get a clean result. Thank you so very much MLmuchAmaze.